# Question about List of Objects in dart Language (Flutter)

Tags: list, class, dart

Question About List of Objects in dart (Flutter)

Hello

---

class Cartoon  {
.
.

}

```
List<Cartoon> L1 = [];

….
...
List<Cartoon> L2 = [];
```

I  define below a new list  L2 containing objects from  List L1 meeting some  condition

```
List<Cartoon> L2 = [];
L2.clear();

for (Cartoon  _thisObjet in L1) {
 if (_thisObjet.xxx == yyyy) { //
   L2.add(_thisObjet);
 }
}
```

I check with the debugger that anytime I modify a member Value in an Object L2 , the member is is also modified in member of. original  Object in List  L1.

This is not expected result

In my mind I was thinking these 2 Lists should be independent ,So if someone has an explanation, I would be grateful

Comment: Would you try to search related to deepcopy?

Answer (score 0):

All variables in Dart is references to objects. The same for lists where lists only contains references to objects.

So your `List<Cartoon>` contains references to `Cartoon` objects. That means that when you look though `L1` you are going though references to `Cartoon` objects and when you insert one of these references to the `L2` list, you now have two lists containing a reference to the same object.

That also means that when you are making changes inside this object, the change can be observed when iterating though both of the lists since there are only one object.

So if you want to prevent a change to a `Cartoon` object to be observed in your other list, you need to make a copy of your `Cartoon` object and make the change on the copy. The best you can do here is to make a method on `Cartoon` which returns a copy of the object or make a constructor which takes a `Cartoon` object to create another `Cartoon` object.

(An important note related to this topic is immutable objects like `int`, `String` and so on (e.g. your own type of objects which only contains `final` fields). These type of objects cannot change their inner state but you are forced to create a new object every time you want to impose a change. By making immutable objects, you can prevent this kind of issues since any change to the object forces you to get a new object. But note, like everything, immutable is not a silver bullet to solve all problems.)